# Code inside subscribe() is not getting executed

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

So what I want to do is get data from the API and depending on the result change the status so the observer of the status gets notified and can act accordingly.

```
fun getQuestionsByRelatedCategoriesFromApi(categoryId: Int, language: String){
        faqFetchStatus.onNext(NetworkStatus.STARTED)
        faqService.getQuestionsOfCategory(categoryId, language)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(
            {
                Log.d("FaqRepository", "Fetching ${it.size} questions from API")
                //adding the language to the question for DB calls
                for (element in it) {
                    element.language = language
                }
                insertQuestionsInDb(it)
                faqFetchStatus.onNext(NetworkStatus.FINISHED)
            },
            {
                faqFetchStatus.onNext(NetworkStatus.FAILED)
            }
        )
    }
```

The `View` calls the `ViewModel` which in return calls the above function in the `Repository`. As expected the status gets changed to "STARTED" and a loading circle is shown. However the subscribe code never gets called which results in an infinite loading loop (form users perspective).

If I remove `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` the code in `subscribe()` gets executed but since it's now a call on the main Thread I recieve the following error.

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So you are saying that the `Log.d("FaqRepository", "Fetching ${it.size} questions from API")` log was never printed?

Comment: What is `faqFetchStatus` and why it is managed like this?

Comment: @ReazMurshed yes and the following commands aswell

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Basically it's a RxJava2 Flowable that is observed using LiveData and when the value changes certain actions are taken

Comment: Nothing is *technically* wrong with the given code. If you can't even see the "Fetching..." log, there could be some problem with `getQuestionOfCategory` implementation.